# referencing programatically added controls in a different event handler?

Tags: c#, button, textbox, event-handling, controls

Alright, so I have a program where I have some textboxes added like this:

```
TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
textbox.Location = new Point(100, 100);
this.Controls.Add(textbox)
```

Just after this I create a button:

```
Button button = new Button();
button.Text = String.Format("Calculate");
button.Location = new Point(70, 70);
this.Controls.Add(button);
```

Because I am adding this in, I need to create my own event handler:

```
button.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
```

The problem I am having is referencing the textbox I created in the event handler I made.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Name property in order to find it:

```
textbox.Name = "myTextBox";

void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (this.Controls.ContainsKey("myTextBox")) {
    TextBox tb = this.Controls["myTextBox"] as TextBox;
    MessageBox.Show(tb.Text);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just store a class-level reference to your text box so you can reference it from within your button event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to store a reference to the TextBox in the Tag Property of your Button:

```
    button.Tag = textbox;
```

Then you can retrieve in your Button Click Handler:

```
    void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)((Button)sender).Tag;
        MessageBox.Show(tb.Text);
    }
```